# Help Proving that $\frac{(1+\frac{1}{t})^t}{e} = 1 -\frac{1}{2t} + O(\frac{1}{t^2})$ for $t\geq 1$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to prove the asymptotic statement that for $t\geq 1$:

$$\frac{(1+\frac{1}{t})^t}{e} = 1 -\frac{1}{2t} + O(\frac{1}{t^2})$$

I know that $(1+\frac{1}{t})^t$ converges to $e$ and the right side looks like the first bit a of the series expansion for $e^{\frac{-1}{2t}}$ but I can't seem to work this thing out.  Can someone point me in the right direction here, I'm new to asymptotic analysis and I don't really know how to deftly manipulate big-O notation yet.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you do, replace $t$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ in your function, then compute Taylor Series at the point $x = 0$. This gives,

> $$1-{\frac {1}{2}}x+{\frac {11}{24}}{x}^{2}-{\frac {7}{16}}{x}^{3}+{
> \frac {2447}{5760}}{x}^{4}+O \left( {x}^{5} \right) $$

Now, substitute $x = \frac{1}{t}$ in the above series yields,

> $$1-{\frac {1}{2t}}+{\frac {11}{24 t^2 }}-{\frac {7}{16 t^3}}+{
> \frac {2447}{5760 t^4}} + O \left( {1/t}^{5} \right)\,.$$

For the big O notation, we say $f$ is a big O of $g$, if $|f(x)|\leq C|g(x)|$. Apply this definition to the above asymptotic series, you get the answer

> $$ 1-{\frac {1}{2t}}+ O \left( {1/t}^{2} \right) \,.$$

Answer (score 5):

We prove by taking logarithm. Let $x = t^{-1}$. Then by the McLaurin expanstion of the logarithm,

$$\log \left[ \frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{t}\right)^{t}}{e} \right]
= \frac{\log(1 + x)}{x} - 1
= -\frac{x}{2} + O(x^2)
= -\frac{1}{2t} + O\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right).$$

Thus exponentiating,

$$ \frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{t}\right)^{t}}{e} = \exp\left[ -\frac{1}{2t} + O\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right) \right] = 1 -\frac{1}{2t} + O\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right). $$

Comment: Thanks for this, very slick, but could you please quickly explain how you derived the final equality?

Comment: Cocktail M: Funny that you ask for an explanation about this (quite detailed) answer and accept another one (which completely omits the step you asked about) 30 minutes later.

Comment: @did: could you explain the missing step for me?

Comment: Cocktail: What for? You accepted the thing, [this can only mean](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3399/6179) that you want *to reward the poster for solving your problem, to inform others that your issue is resolved, and to indicate which answer you think is the most helpful to you*. What could I add to this idyllic picture?

Comment: Cock: I just reread the other post (the one you accepted): the **really** funny thing is that it does not even answer your question! No wonder you ask for more indications afterward...

Comment: *Cocktail M* is now *Ansturm*.

Comment: Ansturm is now banned.